# Can I do array destructuring assignment inside an object declaration?

Tags: javascript

I know I can do this:

```
const [MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED] = [0.4, 4.0];
```

What I want is:

```
const SpeedManager = {
  [MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED]: [0.4, 4.0]
}
```

which is equivalent for:

```
const SpeedManager = {
  MIN_SPEED: 0.4,
  MAX_SPEED: 4.0
}
```

but the syntax was invalid, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible - anything involving *destructuring* will necessary assign values to *references* (either a standalone variable name, or a nested property). But here, you don't have a reference, at least not while still inside the object initializer.

I'd stick with the non-destructuring method, though an ugly alternative is:

```js
const SpeedManager = {};
([SpeedManager.MIN_SPEED, SpeedManager.MAX_SPEED] = [0.4, 4.0]);
console.log(SpeedManager);
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, it isn't possible, an alternative could be to zip the two arrays and then use `Object.fromEntries()` to construct the object for you:

```js
const zip = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.map((e, i) => [e, arr2[i]]);
const res = Object.fromEntries(
  zip(['MIN_SPEED', 'MAX_SPEED'], [0.4, 4.0])
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a step between for getting values from an array and return an object.

```js
const
    convert = ([MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED]) => ({ MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED }),
    speedManager = convert([0.4, 4.0]);

console.log(speedManager);
```